# Integrating Facebook JavaScript SDK in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

What I want to achive is that I want to know if a certain user is login in facebook using my plugin.

What I did is I followed the instructions by [facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus).

Below the `<body>` in my header in wordpress I added

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'my_app_id',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.7'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

*I added my App ID there also*

In the plugin I used the tutorial above on how to identify the user. So I added this code to the plugin

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
    // app, and response.authResponse supplies
    // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
    // request, and the time the access token 
    // and signed request each expire

    var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
    var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;

    document.write('connected');
  } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
    // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
    // but has not authenticated your app
    document.write('not_authorized');
  } else {
    // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
    document.write('not connected');
    }
 });


</script>
```

> But the problem is that it won't work. Nothing is displayed.

Am I doing the right thing? or I am missing something?

Comment: i am not sure what you expect to happen. did you debug the code? "nothing is displayed" is not a sufficient error description, you need be more specific. what about console.log and your browser dev tools? also, there is no login code, so of course the user is never authorized...

Comment: you should read this (and the facebook docs): http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Comment: According to the docs --->>the user is logged into Facebook and has authenticated your application (connected)
-->>>the user is logged into Facebook but has not authenticated your application (not_authorized)
--->>the user is either not logged into Facebook or explicitly logged out of your application so it doesn't attempt to connect to Facebook and thus, we don't know if they've authenticated your application or not (unknown)

Comment: So  I want to see if a user is authenticated or not in my application. I want to display something if yes

Comment: you should not use "document.write", no one does that...use console.log to debug the response. and again, implement authorization. check out the link.

Answer (score 0):

Think is you should show Facebook button for login with facebook. for example:

```
<div class="fb-status text-center">
    <fb:login-button data-size="xlarge" scope="public_profile,email,user_photos">
    </fb:login-button>

    <div id="status">
    </div>
```

Then somehow you need to know that user tried to login with facebook and only then check if user allowed to use his name, email and other options what you defined in scope.

In my plugin was like this. I know that is bad practice, but it works for me.

```
<script>
    fbGalleries.loginStatus = false;

    function checkLoginState() {
            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                statusChangeCallback(response);
            });
            if (fbGalleries.loginStatus == false) {
                setTimeout(checkLoginState, 2000);
            }
            else {
                $('.fb-status').remove();
            }
        }

      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
                appId      : '*****************',
                cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access
                                    // the session
                xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
                version    : 'v2.5' // use graph api version 2.5
            });

        };

        // Load the SDK asynchronously
        (function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    function statusChangeCallback(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            testAPI();
        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
                'into this app.';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
                'into Facebook.';
        }
    }

    function testAPI() {
        FB.api('/me', function(response) {
            console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
                'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
            getFbPhotos(); //in my case pooling user photo galeries
            fbGalleries.loginStatus = true;
        });
    }

</script>
```

Some where you need run `checkLoginState();`